# Is there any maximum limit on number of cookies in java

Tags: java, cookies

```
if (!foundCookie) {
    logger.info("cooookies Not found ---  ");
    ResourceBundle appName = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
        "conf/filename", Locale.getDefault());
    Enumeration bundleKeys = appName.getKeys();
    Cookie[] cookieToBeAdded = new Cookie[9000];

    int i =0 ;
    while (bundleKeys.hasMoreElements()) {    
        logger.error((String) bundleKeys.nextElement());
        String key = (String) bundleKeys.nextElement();
        String value = appName.getString(key);
        cookieToBeAdded[i] = new Cookie(("station" + i),(key+":"+ value));
        cookieToBeAdded[i].setMaxAge(24*60*60);
        logger.error(cookieToBeAdded[i]+"cookieToBeAdded[i]");
        // logger.info("cooookies adding to response ---  " + cookieToBeAdded[i].getName() + ":" + cookieToBeAdded[i].getValue());
        response.addCookie(cookieToBeAdded[i]);

        pw.write("<Source>");
        pw.write("<name>"+value+"</name>");
        pw.write("<id>"+key+"</id>");
        pw.write("</Source>");
        i++;
    }
}
```

I am trying to run the above code and I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.write(InternalOutputBuffer.java:680)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.sendStatus(InternalOutputBuffer.java:419)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1588)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:934)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:183)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

When I try to catch this exception, it does not come into the catch loop. 
I am adding about 8999 values to cookies.
Is there any limit on cookie size?

I am using JBoss and this is written in servlet(Java).

Please help?

Comment: you may want to add more information to your question. when exactly this error occurs? the code you posted doesn't seem to call `arrayCopy`, so I presume the error comes from somewhere else. Anyway, Java will not impose any limit for cookies.

Comment: Thats what is confusing me. Actually that looger line is printed 8973 times. After that its giving the error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
This error stacktrace does not even include the the name of the class where I am writing the code.

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this exception is happening after your servlet code has returned, and Tomcat is creating the response message.  (That explains why you cannot catch the exception, and why you cannot see any of your methods in the stacktrace.)

However, the exception is occurring in a most strange place.  It looks like `write` method is trying to copy data past the end of the message buffer.  But this is happening when it is writing the status line; i.e. the first line of the response.  The only explanation I can think of is

- it has previously tried and failed to write a header containing the cookies,
- it tries to reallocate the buffer and start again, and
- something goes wrong.

I think that the solution is to increase Tomcat's reply buffer size, or reduce the size of the headers.

Comment: Yeah that may be the issue. But aint these heavy images are stored in cookies like orkut, facebook etc. I think that data is even heavier.

Comment: @Vikas - yes, but they have certainly tuned their server-side code to deal with this.  By contrast, you are using Tomcat with (I guess) the default buffer sizes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the tomcat has either a line or header size limit that you're running into.

The real question is why you are trying to use so many cookies. If you have lots of info per user, store it on the session or in a server-side database - don't force it to be sent across the network on every single request.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is not the right way do. But I was just trying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any limitations in any particular server implementation, but there are definite limitations on the size and number of cookies on a browser by browser basis, and of course it varies depending on the browser supplier and version of browser.